# Codename One - Change language bundle after one language was already loaded

Tags: codenameone

My app should enable users to change the language of the UI (for example using a language picker).

I have this line of code that works great in the init():

```
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(map);
```

I use this code to load the default language of the device from a property file. My problem is to change the bundle with a different one during the app running. If I repeat the same line of code with a different map there is no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recreate the `Form`. It doesn't go to each label and refresh it as having it this way would require change listeners on any strings anywhere within your app and would block complex localization logic.

Just invoke the method that shows/creates your form over again and it will use the new locale.